# In which location MediaRecorder saves data in chrome windows?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

Using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) we can record audio and video. On stop recording it fires [ondataavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) event with recorded data as blob. My question is, in which path that blob files get written to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your browser's allocated Memory (in your computer's RAM).

==> It's not written to disk unless you do something that would save it on disk (like asking your user to save it, or store it in one of your browser's Storage Areas.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. You know, the memory increased while recording, how to remove after downloaded the blob. It's not resetting after closing all tabs of browser also.